# From $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{f(x)}$ converges to $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{F(x)}{x}=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> $f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfies that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{f(x)}$ converges.
>
> Prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x}=+\infty$ where $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$.

My attempt:

If we have $f$ is increasing , we can easily get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x)=+\infty$.

Then from L'Hospital rule we get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$

How to deal with the situation that $f$ is not monotonous ? I didn't find a effective method that evaluates $F(x)$ by $f(x)$.

Any hints? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have for all $x>0$,
$$
\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm d t\cdot\int_0^x \frac1{f(t)}\mathrm d t \ge \left(\int_0^x \mathrm dt\right)^2=x^2.
$$ This gives for every $x>0$,
$$
\frac{F(x)}{x}\cdot \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{f(t)} \ge x.
$$ By taking $x\to\infty$, we obtain
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x} \ge \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dt}{f(t)}}=\infty.
$$